# How to customize EC2 instance in Elastic Beanstalk Environment

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a working Elastic Beanstalk environment(PHP 7.3).

```
The ec2 uses Amazon linux2.
I now have to run some userdata ( yum install ... , curl ...) on these ec2 before they start. 
Is this possible ?
I wish userdata was included in Launch configuration.
```

Can any provide some guidance here.
Just as an FYI, I am using cloudformation.

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You **can't directly modify** `UserData` that EB is using on its instances, as the `UserData` is constructed by the EB service based on your setup. You can **access it and view it**, but can't modify from the `CloudFormation` level.

There are **few options** that could potentially server your purpose, depending on your exact needs:

1. User [Resources](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/environment-resources.html) section in your `.ebextensions` to add CloudFormation code to the template that EB is generating.
2. Create [custom AMI](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.customenv.html) to use in place of those provided by EB. This way you can set them up and fine tune to your requirements.
3. Use `.ebextensions` and [platform hooks](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/platforms-linux-extend.html) to install extra software or `curl` webservices you need.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This helps. The custom AMI route is the easiest but will create the extra work of patching the OS myself. Which may not be very scalable. However, I think that adding a Resources section may serve my purpose. I am a bit confused and hoping to get some guidance. Here will be my steps -- 1. Add a Resource section to the CF template: but which resource do I mention here. Ideally, it should be the launch configuration? Do you have a sample file? Thanks

Comment: @Judi The LC is already set by EB. I'm not sure you can directly modify it. You could add resources, such as `AWS::AutoScaling::LifecycleHook` as shown [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/environment-resources.html). But if you want to run only `yum` or `curl` what's wrong with using `.ebextensions`?

Comment: Thanks, I will try both but looks like .ebextensions should be most suited for my case.